# F# - creating delegates

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#, unit-type

Currently reading a series of blogposts on F#, targeted at the C# programmer. Right now I've finished reading part 3 ( http://www.jelovic.com/weblog/?p=220 ) and am left puzzled.

The difference between

> let readLine = Console.ReadLine ()

and

> let readLine () = Console.ReadLine ()

is clear enough but why is there the need to specify the two braces - () - in the following line:

> let print (text : string) () = Console.WriteLine text

Shouldn't the compiler be able to figure out you're declaring a delegate print by omitting the braces, so it would look as follows:

> let print (text : string)  = Console.WriteLine text

Also, the following line made little sense to me

> Usually when you have a function that takes parameters of a different type the compiler can differentiate between a function call and a delegate reference, but for unit you have to force it.

Does this mean that when the parameters are different it is safe for the compiler to assume it's a function call?

thank you all for the answers, it's clear to me now. As for the quote, we'll let it rest.

Comment: If you are coming to F# from C#, you may find these useful: http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/04/03/f-function-types-fun-with-tuples-and-currying/  and  http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/11/28/what-does-this-c-code-look-like-in-f-part-one-expressions-and-statements/

Comment: The most confusing aspect of the blog is the use of `print` as the name of the function, when a better name is `makePrinter`, since it takes a string and returns a function that will print that string.

Comment: Regarding the quote, I'm not really sure what is the author trying to say, so I cannot help (it doesn't make much sense to me either). Possibly, he just tries to highlight the fact that there is a difference between _value_ and _function_ declarations in F#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Introduction.** I think it's useful to first discuss the difference in the simple example as it helps to understand what "unit" value is. The first declaration creates a string value (and immediately calls `ReadLine` to obtain the input from the user):

```
> let readLine = Console.ReadLine ();;
val readLine : string
```

The second declaration creates a function that takes unit value as an argument. The function doesn't need to take any input, but we want to define it as a function, so that it can be executed repeatedly (we need that, because the function has *side-effect* - it reads input from the user).

The "unit" parameter is just a way of creating a function that takes something as argument. "Unit" has only a single value written as `()`, so it doesn't represent any information - just the fact that there is some parameter:

```
> let readLine () = Console.ReadLine ();;
val readLine : unit -> string
```

**Your question.** To look at your example with additional braces. This creates a function that takes a string as the first parameter and takes additional "unit" value as the second parameter. You can see that from the type signature:

```
> let print (text : string) () = Console.WriteLine text 
val print : string -> unit -> unit
```

This is valid F# declaration, but it is not very useful. It means that the function will be only called when you give it some string to print and also additional "unit" value. You can call it like this:

```
print "Hello" ()
```

Even without the additional "unit" parameter, it would be a function (as opposed to a value), so adding the additional parameter doesn't help (you're always creating a function that can be called to print different strings).

There are still cases where this declaration can be interesting. For example, you can call the function just with the string as a parameter. In this case, you'll get a function as the result. The returned function will take unit and will print the string:

```
let f = print "Hello" // doesn't print anything
f ()                  // prints "Hello"
f ()                  // prints "Hello" again!
```

So, the compiler allows you to use "unit" values as any other values in the language. This includes uses that may look a bit unfamiliar (and not very useful) at first, but can make a good sense in some scenario.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
let print (text : string) = Console.WriteLine text
```

creates a method to print like:

```
print "hi" // prints "hi" in the console
```

where:

```
let print (text : string) () = Console.WriteLine text
```

produces a method to print a specific string like:

```
let printHi = print "hi" // Does NOT print a string to the console

printHi () // But now this does print "hi" :)
printHi () // And this...
```

So essentially, it is a "print specific string X to console function" factory which the result (ex printHi) can be reused many times.

Answer (score 2):

Using currying,

```
let makePrinter (text : string) () = Console.WriteLine text
```

let's you create a function that always prints a certain string, for instance

```
let helloPrinter = makePrinter "hello"
```

gives "hello" by simply calling

```
helloPrinter ()
```

On the other hand,

```
let print (text : string) = Console.WriteLine text
```

immediatly outputs "text" if called

```
print "hello"
```

and returns (), not a function of type `unit -> unit` as in the first, curried case.

Comment: No prob (sorry for doing more editing than I initially intended)